# Getting files/folders from sharepoint via the api in c#

Tags: c#, rest, file, sharepoint, directory

I'm trying to link a c# application to a sharepoint directory, so I can create folders, download and upload files. However I am strugling with connecting to the correct folder.

I can retrieve the content from allitems.aspx, but I am not sure how to actually get the content from folder.

I have tried using the ClientContext - something like this:

```
        ClientContext cxt = new ClientContext("https://xx.sharepoint.com/sites/");

        cxt.Credentials = GetCredentials();

        List list = cxt.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Kontrakter");
        var test = list.Views;
        var test1 = cxt.Web.Lists;

        cxt.Load(test1);
        cxt.Load(list);
        cxt.Load(test);
        var a = 4;

        var fullUri = new Uri("https://xx.sharepoint.com/sites/yy/Kontrakter/AllItems.aspx");
        //var folder = cxt.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(fullUri.AbsolutePath);

        using (var rootCtx = new ClientContext(fullUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority))) 
        {
            rootCtx.Credentials = GetCredentials();
            Uri webUri = Web.WebUrlFromPageUrlDirect(rootCtx, fullUri);  
            using (var ctx1 = new ClientContext(webUri))
            {
                ctx1.Credentials = GetCredentials();

                var list1 = ctx1.Web.GetList(fullUri.AbsolutePath); 
                ctx1.Load(list1.RootFolder.Files);
                ctx1.ExecuteQuery();

                Console.WriteLine(list.RootFolder.Files.Count);


            }
        }
```

or via normal api calls like this:

https://xx.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Kontrakter/Forms')/Files

The only way I can find some data is if I look into 'Shared documents/Forms'

I'm having problems understanding the directory structure and how I can actually find the content of files/folders.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The old way is to use FTP GetDirectory (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-list-directory-contents-with-ftp) or get from a shared folder using window methods.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I was missing a /sites in one of my uris.